# How can I reliably merge objects from these 2 arrays and loop the resulting array, in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have 2 arrays of objects, with each object containing info I wish to merge. The arrays have one common key:

```
let countries = [
    { code: "AF", name: "Afghanistan" },
    { code: "AL", name: "Albania" },
    { code: "IL", name: "Israel" },
]

let dial = [
    { code: "AF", dial_code: "+93" },
    { code: "AL",  dial_code: "+355" },
    { code: "IL", dial_code: "+972" },
]
```

I merged the above arrays into a *new* one this way:

```
let merged = countries.map((item, i) => Object.assign({}, item, dial[i]));
```

Then I display the info in a table, using Svelte:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Code</th>
      <th>Dial Code</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {#if countries.length}
    {#each merged as m} 
    <tr>
      <td>{m.name}</td>
      <td>{m.code}</td>
      <td>{m.dial_code}</td>
    </tr>
    {/each}
    {:else}
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">There are no countries</td>
    </tr>
    {/if}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The method works as can be seen [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/cfa13c4563734d21990b72514cc249a4?version=3.23.2), but is not "bulletproof": if the objects are not ordered the same, by the `code` key, the method returns bad/false results.

What method would work even if the `dial` array would look like below?

```
let dial = [
    { code: "IL", dial_code: "+972" },
    { code: "AF", dial_code: "+93" },
    { code: "AL",  dial_code: "+355" },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is  different approach

```js
let countries = [
  { code: "AF", name: "Afghanistan" },
  { code: "AL", name: "Albania" },
  { code: "IL", name: "Israel" },
]

let dial = [
  { code: "AF", dial_code: "+93" },
  { code: "AL",  dial_code: "+355" },
  { code: "IL", dial_code: "+972" },
  { code: "ILi", dial_code: "+972" }
]


result=[]
dial.forEach((x)=>{
    countries.forEach(o=>{
    if(x.code==o.code)
      return result.push(Object.assign({},o,x))
  })
 })
  
    
console.log(result)
```

Comment: What if I want the `result` array to contain only `name` and `dial_code` properties, how do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Some of the answers here are essentially using nested loops (a `forEach` inside a `forEach`, or a `find` inside a `map`). That's probably fine in this situation, but the performance of this approach is O(n^2), which is a red flag. If you had a *third* array of data that you wanted to merge with a similar approach, it would become O(n^3), and so on.

A much more scalable solution is to use lookups:

```js
const sources = [countries, dial]; // plus anything you add in future!

const codes = new Set( // using a set is an easy way to dedupe
  sources.map(source => source.map(d => d.code)).flat()
);

const lookups = sources.map(source => {
  const lookup = new Map();
  source.forEach(d => lookup.set(d.code, d));
  return lookup;
});

const combined = Array.from(codes, code => {
  return Object.assign({}, ...lookups.map(d => d.get(code) || {}));
});
```

Comment: very beautiful solution. However, I have run a performance test with your solution vs the nested foreach, and it seems at least in this situation that this solution is slower that the nested foreach, also it seems to add unwanted data in situation where the arrays are not of same length, but maybe that can be circumvented though

Comment: The approach can easily be modified to use the set of all codes that appear in both sources or in either. Re performance: yes, obviously when you have three items the technique with the least amount of setup will win. But that's not the thing to optimise for. The approach here is O(n), whereas the `forEach` approach is O(n^2) in the best case. The data in question is a list of countries, of which there are ~200 — with that amount of data, the O(n) algorithm is already several times faster than the naive `forEach` approach. With (say) 10,000 items, O(n^2) is catastrophically slow.

Comment: Thank you for you comment, I agree the solution is scalable and it's definitely faster for large data but wouldn't you consider the last line in your solution a kind of nested loop? since you are using `Array.from ` to iterate through the keys  and inside it a `map` to iterate through the `Map` and they both make copies of the array since the Array.from internal mechanism uses `map` as well? is it possible to avoid the Array.from and map been nested?

Comment: @Sven.hig, the difference is that `...lookups.map(...)` loops over 2 lookups, not _n_ rows of data. That's why this is O(n) and not O(n^2). As an aside, I very much doubt that `Array.from` is using `map` internally; there's no reason why it would

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to use `reduce` by merging both arrays in to one and then taking Object.values of it. Here is an example:

```js
var dial = [  { code: "IL", dial_code: "+972" }, { code: "AF", dial_code: "+93" }, { code: "AL",  dial_code: "+355" },];

var countries = [ { code: "AF", name: "Afghanistan" }, { code: "AL", name: "Albania" },{ code: "IL", name: "Israel" }];

var result = Object.values([...dial, ...countries].reduce((acc, elem)=>{
    acc[elem.code] = {...(acc[elem.code] || {}), ...elem};
    return acc;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

Or you can also make use of `map` and `find`:

```js
var dial = [  { code: "IL", dial_code: "+972" }, { code: "AF", dial_code: "+93" }, { code: "AL",  dial_code: "+355" },];

var countries = [ { code: "AF", name: "Afghanistan" }, { code: "AL", name: "Albania" },{ code: "IL", name: "Israel" }];

var result= countries.map(country=>({...country, dialo_code:dial.find(p=>p.code==country.code)?.dial_code}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Which of the methods would work even if  the 2 arrays were *unequal* in length?

Comment: Which array in that case would be the defining one for the new length?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir both will work. In case of `reduce`, say if dial_code not present then it will not insert the key in object, and if you will use second, key will be there but with undefined value. Better you can test it on your with some dummy data. and choose one.

Answer (score 1):

I think sorting is much more efficient than doing a builtin data structure.

```
let countries = [
  { code: "AF", name: "Afghanistan" },
  { code: "AL", name: "Albania" },
  { code: "IL", name: "Israel" },
]

let dial = [
  { code: "AF", dial_code: "+93" },
  { code: "AL",  dial_code: "+355" },
  { code: "IL", dial_code: "+972" },
]

const combine = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const combined = arr1.concat(arr2)
  combined.sort((x, y) => x.code.localeCompare(y.code))
  const result = [combined[0]]
  for (let i = 1; i < combined.length; i++) {
    if (combined[i].code == combined[i - 1].code) {
      result[result.length - 1] = { ...result[result.length - 1], ...combined[i] }
    } else {
      result.push(combined[i])
    }
  }

  return result
}

console.log(combine(countries, dial))
```